# Amazon web services and mysql c++ connector cannot connect to RDS instance from EC2 instace

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, mysql-connector

I'm programming a server application in c++ that will connect to a RDS instance from an EC2 instance and do your average database stuff. I've been working on the software for a few weeks, and today I hit the step where I need to connect to a db and interact with some data. I can't seem to get it to connect, everytime I get an exception saying `Unknown MySQL server host` (code 2005), but the odd part is that I can use the mysql command in ssh with the same url and machine and it works just fine. My code is as follows:

```
    dbDriverPtr driver(get_driver_instance());

    LOG(trace) << "Starting " << driver->getName();

    dbConnectionPtr conn(driver->connect(sql::SQLString("tcp://mydb.abcdef.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"), sql::SQLString("user"), sql::SQLString("password")));
    LOG(trace) << "SQL connected to Auth Server";

    conn->setSchema("Auth");

    dbStatementPtr stmt(conn->createStatement());
    dbResultPtr res(stmt->executeQuery("select id,displayname from users order by id desc"));
    while (res->next())
    {
        LOG(trace) << res->getString("id") << ":" << res->getString("displayname");
    }
```

Note that the pointer types are just auto_ptr typedefs.

I've tried variations of tcp, the port, and resolving the url to ip (that *really* didn't work), and the only consistency was failure. What am I missing here?

I should note that I'm using the default ubuntu 14.4 64bit server instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for anyone that comes by this. It turned out to have nothing to do with aws, but my build configuration. I was statically linking the boost libraries and dynamically linking others. Somehow that goofed up my dns stuff so that getaddrinfo was failing.